# how to me to break this helper into two methods and to use it in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code.

```
def links_in_body(comment_text)
  # show short part of link
  regex_url = %r{^(http|https):\/\/|[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$}
  comment_text.gsub!(regex_url) { |link| truncate(link, length: 30) }

  # detect links to site's videos and show title
  regex = %r{http:\/\/#{request.host_with_port}(\/[\w\/]+)[\.,!\s]?}
  comment_text.gsub(regex) do |matched|
    params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.path

    # if the link we found was a video link, replaced matched string with
    # an anchor tag to the video, with the video title as the link text
    if params[:controller] == 'videos' && params[:action] == 'show' 
       video = Video.find params[:id]
       link_to "#{video.title}&nbsp;".html_safe, video_path(video)
    # otherwise just return the string without any modifications
    else
       matched
    end
  end
end
```

I decided to use gem https://github.com/vmg/rinku for code abbreviation.

It turned out so.

```
def links_in_body(comment_text)
  # show short part of link
  Rinku.auto_link(comment_text) do |url|
    truncate(link, length: 30)
  end

  # detect links to site's videos and show title
  regex = %r{http:\/\/#{request.host_with_port}(\/[\w\/]+)[\.,!\s]?}
  comment_text.gsub(regex) do |matched|
    params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.path

    # if the link we found was a video link, replaced matched string with
    # an anchor tag to the video, with the video title as the link text
    if params[:controller] == 'videos' && params[:action] == 'show' 
       video = Video.find params[:id]
       link_to "#{video.title}&nbsp;".html_safe, video_path(video)
    # otherwise just return the string without any modifications
    else
       matched
    end
  end
end
```

But part of a code after "# detect links to site's videos and show title" doesn't work.

views:

```
= links_in_body(comment.body).html_safe
```

how to me to break this helper into two methods and to use it in views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing a tiny piece of code here. you need to pass the string that rinku `auto_link` method returns. this might be a cleaner solution:

```
def links_in_body(text)
  text = auto_link(text) { |url| truncate(link, length: 30) }
  auto_link_video(text)
end

def auto_link_video(text)
  regex = %r{http:\/\/#{request.host_with_port}(\/[\w\/]+)[\.,!\s]?}
  text.gsub(regex) do |matched|
    if controller_name == 'videos' && action_name == 'show' 
       video = Video.find params[:id]
       link_to "#{video.title}&nbsp;".html_safe, video_path(video)
    else
       matched
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

DRY:

```
def links_in_body(text)
  auto_link(text) do |url|
    video_id = url.match(/\Ahttps?:\/\/#{request.host_with_port}\/videos\/(\d+)\z/)
    if video_id.present?
      Video.find(video_id[1]).title
    else
      truncate(url, length: AppConfig.truncate.length)
    end
  end
end
```